# Does Sql batch query execution involve multiple exhange of data between server and client?

Tags: sql, jdbc

Batch query execution from what I have read from multiple sources online have been stating that it enables grouping multiple statements together and executing it at once, thereby eliminating multiple back and forth communication.

Some sources that claim this are:

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm#:~:text=Batch%20Processing%20allows%20you%20to,communication%20overhead%2C%20thereby%20improving%20performance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm#:%7E:text=Batch%20Processing%20allows%20you%20to,communication%20overhead%2C%20thereby%20improving%20performance).

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html

https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing

All of these talk about single network trip etc, however going through the source code of H2 or Sqlite, it does look like its executing one by one. Albeit with autocommit disabled.

Eg: Sqlite

```
final synchronized int[] executeBatch(long stmt, int count, Object[] vals, boolean autoCommit) throws SQLException {
        if (count < 1) {
            throw new SQLException("count (" + count + ") < 1");
        }

        final int params = bind_parameter_count(stmt);

        int rc;
        int[] changes = new int[count];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                reset(stmt);
                for (int j = 0; j < params; j++) {
                    rc = sqlbind(stmt, j, vals[(i * params) + j]);
                    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
                        throwex(rc);
                    }
                }

                rc = step(stmt);
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
                    reset(stmt);
                    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
                        throw new BatchUpdateException("batch entry " + i + ": query returns results", changes);
                    }
                    throwex(rc);
                }

                changes[i] = changes();
            }
        }
        finally {
            ensureAutoCommit(autoCommit);
        }

        reset(stmt);
        return changes;
    }
```

Eg: H2

```
public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException {
        try {
            debugCodeCall("executeBatch");
            if (batchParameters == null) {
                // Empty batch is allowed, see JDK-4639504 and other issues
                batchParameters = Utils.newSmallArrayList();
            }
            batchIdentities = new MergedResult();
            int size = batchParameters.size();
            int[] result = new int[size];
            SQLException first = null;
            SQLException last = null;
            checkClosedForWrite();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Value[] set = batchParameters.get(i);
                ArrayList<? extends ParameterInterface> parameters =
                        command.getParameters();
                for (int j = 0; j < set.length; j++) {
                    Value value = set[j];
                    ParameterInterface param = parameters.get(j);
                    param.setValue(value, false);
                }
                try {
                    result[i] = executeUpdateInternal();
                    // Cannot use own implementation, it returns batch identities
                    ResultSet rs = super.getGeneratedKeys();
                    batchIdentities.add(((JdbcResultSet) rs).result);
                } catch (Exception re) {
                    SQLException e = logAndConvert(re);
                    if (last == null) {
                        first = last = e;
                    } else {
                        last.setNextException(e);
                    }
                    result[i] = Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED;
                }
            }
            batchParameters = null;
            if (first != null) {
                throw new JdbcBatchUpdateException(first, result);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw logAndConvert(e);
        }
    }
```

From the above code I see that there are multiple calls to the database, with each having its own result set. How does batch execution actually work?

Comment: Very good question +1. However, I would hardly consider SQLite a highly optimized database engine. I would consider these two engines are not optimized for network traffic (they are small ones). I would think, however, that PostgreSQL or MariaDB have a much better implementation; they are both open source so it's possible to look at the code. But this is just speculation since I haven't looked into it myself.

Comment: Just thinking about it... maybe HyperSQL or Apache Derby behave differently. They are also open source, and can also work in embedded mode.

Comment: Looking through Mysql, since we are using it, will also check PostgreSql.

Comment: @TheImpaler
Looked at mysql code https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/StatementImpl.java
looks like even here they are executing one by one. Am I missing something or the online resources claiming a single trip have got it wrong. Looked at the methods 

`executeBatch` which in turn calls `executeBatchInternal` which has a for loop iterating through the queries and calls a overloaded `executeUpdateInternal` which then calls
`execSQL(this, sql, -1, null, false, getResultSetFactory(), null, isBatch);`

Comment: Very interesting. The spec says it should do it. I wonder if the server side just queues the calls when `isBatch` is set; maybe it doesn't run them one by one, but by batches. Probably even if you wanted to batch 10 million calls, the engine will pipeline them and will run them 100 at a time (just speculating). But your research is quite enlightening. As a final note, the PostgreSQL guys really implemented the engine well; if PostgreSQL is doing the same thing, then there's something we're understanding the wrong way here.